# Alert Box with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

Is it possible to add Alert box with CSS attributes?

**For my code is that**

```
if (username==null) {
    alert("Please Fill Up Required Field");
}

else {
    XXX
}
```

**My code for my alert style**

```
<style>
.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

The Result that I want : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_alert

But I always get this: https://gyazo.com/88f00fdf2654367aa148b033c8832698

Comment: `alert` is not an element it is a function, how can you add css to a function like that?

Comment: Notice the HTML code in the W3Schools example. There's a div.alert (`<div class="alert">`) element--not the alert window--that's being styled. Could you help clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @stealththeninja  trying to implement a alert box when user click on register button. but the original alert box is too plain, wanted to add the style that from w3school

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're using the `alert` function:

```
alert("Please Fill Up Required Field");
```

You can't style this - it's a browser-generated box. You need to use a [modal box](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp), and then you can style it.

Answer (score 1):

In the W3schools example, they are not adding the CSS attributes to the alert element, but to a class on a div:

`<div class="alert">`

I'd recommend going their route and just making a Div appear to be an alert by changing the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The alert box is a system object, and not subject to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the alert() functionality. The jQuery UI Modal box does a lot of the work for you, working basically as I have described: [Link](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).