# Jquery alert() to modal after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, alert

I need to change alert(); return to modal after ajax success. I used this jQuery code :
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdfx0rt6o80hvga/jquery.form.bassm.js)

What is the best solution to change bad design alert to nice modal ?
Thank you
David

Comment: Please go through following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the alert apearance. You have to make your own alert.
You can use bootstrap Modal if you want. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

You can see this topics:

[How to change the style of alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

[Alert Box with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902344/alert-box-with-css)

[How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

Comment: Thank I've seen it, but I'd like to keep the return (success, errors..)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that SweetAlert is best for you:
[Follow the link](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)